# XML parsing in java: how to get info out of a tag adjacent to a tag with a certain value?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I am trying to get information out of an XML file, and use this information to create objects. The problem is that every tag in the XML file is dict, key, or a data type tag like integer, and String. with these vague tag names, i'm finding it difficult to specify the data that i want.

I realise that i'm not asking this in the best way, but i'm a complete beginner and don't know where to start, any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the file i'm trying to parse from:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Date</key><date>2012-10-27T17:24:27Z</date>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>10.7</string>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Music Folder</key><string>file://localhost/C:/Users/andrea/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/</string>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>69A7F174F7AEE335</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>2651</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>2651</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Munastero 'e Santa Chiara</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>A.M.P</string>
            <key>Composer</key><string>Barberis A., Galvieri</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>Bella Napoli</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>World</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>File audio AAC</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>2378728</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>149520</integer>
            <key>Disc Number</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Disc Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Track Number</key><integer>14</integer>
            <key>Track Count</key><integer>15</integer>
            <key>Year</key><integer>2007</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2011-06-07T13:22:48Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2008-10-12T11:50:56Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>123</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>3</integer>
            <key>Play Date</key><integer>3367816684</integer>
            <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2010-09-20T06:38:04Z</date>
            <key>Compilation</key><true/>
            <key>Artwork Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Sort Album</key><string>Bella Napoli</string>
            <key>Sort Artist</key><string>A.M.P</string>
            <key>Sort Composer</key><string>Barberis A., Galvieri</string>
            <key>Sort Name</key><string>Munastero 'e Santa Chiara</string>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>0000000000000376</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/C:/Users/andrea/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Compilations/Bella%20Napoli/14%20Munastero%20'e%20Santa%20Chiara.m4a</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>2653</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>2653</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Traccia 01</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>A6 ALLROAD</string>
            <key>Album Artist</key><string>A6 ALLROAD</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>2008 TUTTI SUCCESSI</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>File audio MPEG</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>5888463</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>245263</integer>
            <key>Track Number</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Track Count</key><integer>20</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2008-01-18T08:12:30Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2008-01-18T08:36:02Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>192</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>28</integer>
            <key>Play Date</key><integer>3419616065</integer>
            <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2012-05-11T19:21:05Z</date>
            <key>Skip Date</key><date>2012-02-01T03:48:19Z</date>
            <key>Sort Album</key><string>2008 TUTTI SUCCESSI</string>
            <key>Sort Album Artist</key><string>A6 ALLROAD</string>
            <key>Sort Artist</key><string>A6 ALLROAD</string>
            <key>Sort Name</key><string>Traccia 01</string>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>0000000000000377</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/C:/Users/andrea/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/A6%20ALLROAD/2008%20TUTTI%20SUCCESSI/01%20Traccia%2001.mp3</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>5</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>2655</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>2655</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Traccia 02</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>A6 ALLROAD</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>2008 TUTTI SUCCESSI</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>File audio MPEG</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>4675349</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>194716</integer>
            <key>Track Number</key><integer>2</integer>
            <key>Track Count</key><integer>20</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2008-01-18T08:12:30Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2008-01-18T08:36:44Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>192</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>25</integer>
            <key>Play Date</key><integer>3419616259</integer>
            <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2012-05-11T19:24:19Z</date>
            <key>Skip Date</key><date>2012-07-15T11:12:37Z</date>
            <key>Sort Album</key><string>2008 TUTTI SUCCESSI</string>
            <key>Sort Artist</key><string>A6 ALLROAD</string>
            <key>Sort Name</key><string>Traccia 02</string>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>0000000000000378</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/C:/Users/andrea/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/A6%20ALLROAD/2008%20TUTTI%20SUCCESSI/02%20Traccia%2002.mp3</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>5</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
```

this isn't the full file but you get the idea.
i'm trying to get the relevent information to pass into the attributes and create this object but i don't know where to start:

```
package entities;

public class Track {

private int id;
private String name;
private String artist;
private String composer;
private String album;
private String genre;
private String kind;
private int size;
private int totalTime;
private int discNumber;
private int discCount;
private int trackNumber;
private int trackCount;
private int year;
private int dateModified;
private int dateAdded;
private int bitRate;
private int playCount;
private int playDate;
private int playDateUTC;
private boolean compilation;
private int artworkCount;
private String sortAlbum;
private String sortArtist;
private String sortComposer;
private String persistantID;
private String trackType;
private String location;
private int fileFolderCount;
private int libraryFolderCount;
public Track(int id, String name, String artist, String composer, String album, String genre, String kind, int size,
        int totalTime, int discNumber, int discCount, int trackNumber, int trackCount, int year, int dateModified,
        int dateAdded, int bitRate, int playCount, int playDate, int playDateUTC, boolean compilation,
        int artworkCount, String sortAlbum, String sortArtist, String sortComposer, String persistantID,
        String trackType, String location, int fileFolderCount, int libraryFolderCount) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.composer = composer;
    this.album = album;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.kind = kind;
    this.size = size;
    this.totalTime = totalTime;
    this.discNumber = discNumber;
    this.discCount = discCount;
    this.trackNumber = trackNumber;
    this.trackCount = trackCount;
    this.year = year;
    this.dateModified = dateModified;
    this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    this.bitRate = bitRate;
    this.playCount = playCount;
    this.playDate = playDate;
    this.playDateUTC = playDateUTC;
    this.compilation = compilation;
    this.artworkCount = artworkCount;
    this.sortAlbum = sortAlbum;
    this.sortArtist = sortArtist;
    this.sortComposer = sortComposer;
    this.persistantID = persistantID;
    this.trackType = trackType;
    this.location = location;
    this.fileFolderCount = fileFolderCount;
    this.libraryFolderCount = libraryFolderCount;
}
public Track() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}
public void setArtist(String artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
}
public String getComposer() {
    return composer;
}
public void setComposer(String composer) {
    this.composer = composer;
}
public String getAlbum() {
    return album;
}
public void setAlbum(String album) {
    this.album = album;
}
public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}
public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}
public String getKind() {
    return kind;
}
public void setKind(String kind) {
    this.kind = kind;
}
public int getSize() {
    return size;
}
public void setSize(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}
public int getTotalTime() {
    return totalTime;
}
public void setTotalTime(int totalTime) {
    this.totalTime = totalTime;
}
public int getDiscNumber() {
    return discNumber;
}
public void setDiscNumber(int discNumber) {
    this.discNumber = discNumber;
}
public int getDiscCount() {
    return discCount;
}
public void setDiscCount(int discCount) {
    this.discCount = discCount;
}
public int getTrackNumber() {
    return trackNumber;
}
public void setTrackNumber(int trackNumber) {
    this.trackNumber = trackNumber;
}
public int getTrackCount() {
    return trackCount;
}
public void setTrackCount(int trackCount) {
    this.trackCount = trackCount;
}
public int getYear() {
    return year;
}
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}
public int getDateModified() {
    return dateModified;
}
public void setDateModified(int dateModified) {
    this.dateModified = dateModified;
}
public int getDateAdded() {
    return dateAdded;
}
public void setDateAdded(int dateAdded) {
    this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
}
public int getBitRate() {
    return bitRate;
}
public void setBitRate(int bitRate) {
    this.bitRate = bitRate;
}
public int getPlayCount() {
    return playCount;
}
public void setPlayCount(int playCount) {
    this.playCount = playCount;
}
public int getPlayDate() {
    return playDate;
}
public void setPlayDate(int playDate) {
    this.playDate = playDate;
}
public int getPlayDateUTC() {
    return playDateUTC;
}
public void setPlayDateUTC(int playDateUTC) {
    this.playDateUTC = playDateUTC;
}
public boolean isCompilation() {
    return compilation;
}
public void setCompilation(boolean compilation) {
    this.compilation = compilation;
}
public int getArtworkCount() {
    return artworkCount;
}
public void setArtworkCount(int artworkCount) {
    this.artworkCount = artworkCount;
}
public String getSortAlbum() {
    return sortAlbum;
}
public void setSortAlbum(String sortAlbum) {
    this.sortAlbum = sortAlbum;
}
public String getSortArtist() {
    return sortArtist;
}
public void setSortArtist(String sortArtist) {
    this.sortArtist = sortArtist;
}
public String getSortComposer() {
    return sortComposer;
}
public void setSortComposer(String sortComposer) {
    this.sortComposer = sortComposer;
}
public String getPersistantID() {
    return persistantID;
}
public void setPersistantID(String persistantID) {
    this.persistantID = persistantID;
}
public String getTrackType() {
    return trackType;
}
public void setTrackType(String trackType) {
    this.trackType = trackType;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
public int getFileFolderCount() {
    return fileFolderCount;
}
public void setFileFolderCount(int fileFolderCount) {
    this.fileFolderCount = fileFolderCount;
}
public int getLibraryFolderCount() {
    return libraryFolderCount;
}
public void setLibraryFolderCount(int libraryFolderCount) {
    this.libraryFolderCount = libraryFolderCount;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Track [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", artist=" + artist + ", composer=" + composer + ", album="
            + album + ", genre=" + genre + ", kind=" + kind + ", size=" + size + ", totalTime=" + totalTime
            + ", discNumber=" + discNumber + ", discCount=" + discCount + ", trackNumber=" + trackNumber
            + ", trackCount=" + trackCount + ", year=" + year + ", dateModified=" + dateModified + ", dateAdded="
            + dateAdded + ", bitRate=" + bitRate + ", playCount=" + playCount + ", playDate=" + playDate
            + ", playDateUTC=" + playDateUTC + ", compilation=" + compilation + ", artworkCount=" + artworkCount
            + ", sortAlbum=" + sortAlbum + ", sortArtist=" + sortArtist + ", sortComposer=" + sortComposer
            + ", persistantID=" + persistantID + ", trackType=" + trackType + ", location=" + location
            + ", fileFolderCount=" + fileFolderCount + ", libraryFolderCount=" + libraryFolderCount + "]";
}





}
```

this is what i have so far:

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import entities.Track;

public class Main {

Main() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    ArrayList<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>(); 
    File xmlFile = new File("iTunes Music Library1.xml");

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
    System.out.println("Root element " +doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("dict");

    for(int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++) {
        Node node = nList.item(i);
        NodeList childList=node.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("Current Element: "+node.getNodeName());

        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new Main();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a SAX Parser. Your implementing class will get called for the start/end of each object in the XML file, and you're going to have to write something intelligent that understands the structure of your file. That is, remember the last key so you know when you get a value, what it's a value for.

If you've never written code using a SAX Parser, this is going to take you some time, but you'll learn a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I'll definitely look into a SAX Parser. We were taught to use this parser in college, but i'll check if they would mind me using a different one.